# HSM PIN Command for Customer selected PIN

Tags: hsm

I am trying to build a card pin solution whereby customers are able to logon to a web portal and set their own card PIN and afterwards generate a PVV value of the new PIN.

The list of commands I trying to use are

- JG\JH (Translate PIN)
- DG\DH (Generate PVV)

The JG\JH command requires a PIN under LMK which means I need to do a BA\BB command on the customer PIN first before I can proceed. To do this the HSM must be in an authorized state.

Is there a different way of achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you show us what you have tried so far? Take a look here [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to give us some more info

Answer (score 0):

Well, the right way is to do it in a similar manner as it would have been on an ATM terminal.

**1. Create a clear PIN block**

> ```
> For ex.
> PIN = 1234
> PAN = 400000000000002
>
> Block 1 [0+Pin Length+Filler to make it 16]: 0+   4+1234+FFFFFFFFFF = 41234FFFFFFFFFF
> Block 2 [0000 + PAN(12, exclude first 3 and last check digit)]: 0000 +    000000000000 = 0000000000000000 
>
> Clear PIN Block = XOR(Block 1 , Block 2)
> ```

**2. Encrypt (apply 3DES) clear PIN block under ZPK.**

> If you are using java then try javax.crypto.Cipher.

**3. Use encrypted PIN Block in command "FW" to generate PVV**

> - Command Code (FW)
> - PIN Encryption Key Type (001 for ZPK)
> - PIN Encryption Key (ZPK)
> - PIN Verification Key
> - PIN Block
> - PIN Block Format Code
> - PAN/Account(12)
> - PVKI